# Find and redirect to appropriate email client based on email address

Tags: javascript, email, user-experience

I want to add a **confirm email address** link similar to what **trello** does. Based on which email client you use I want to redirect user to appropriate url.

For example:

If a user has **example@gmail.com** then the link should open **mail.google.com**.
If the User has **example@outlook.com** it should open outlook's link.

Moreover, if an user has their company's email address and they uses gmail as their email client, I want to find their email client and try to redirect there. This could reduce the friction where user need to manually navigate to their email client to check and confirm their email.

Is there any simpler way we could achieve this?

Comment: AFAIK, `mail.google.com` is same as `gmail.com`. so why not take last two parts and open those link and handle the exceptions carefully

Comment: Hey @bugwheels94, we could do that but there are cases when you are using your organization's email address. If your email address is **hey@example.com**, you could still be using G Suite so, you still want to redirect to **mail.google.com** instead of **example.com**

Comment: This is a case you will never be able to handle. Only solution is you have a specific list of domains and emails mapping, preferably stored on server and you query that to decide the href for anchor